# Unable to match input string with ')' before the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am having problems in writing a regular expression to match strings like following:

```
var p1=@VAL([Test1Q1].[Bandwidth])
var p2=@VAL([Test1Q1].[Usages (KB)])
```

The pattern should match inputs that start with `@VAL(` and end with a first bracket `)` and capture the following (from the above inputs):

```
[Test1Q1].[Bandwidth]
[Test1Q1].[Usages (KB)]
```

I have tried with the following expression:

```
var fieldPattern = /@VAL\((.*)\)/;
var P1_Pattern = p1.match(fieldPattern );
var P2_Pattern = p2.match(fieldPattern );
```

I got the correct match for `p1` but the wrong result for `p2`.  For `p2` I got

```
[Test1Q1].[Usages (KB
```

but need the following result instead:

```
[Test1Q1].[Usages (KB)]
```

I know it happens because `)` occurs before the end of `p2`; but I am unable to sort it out.  How can I modify my regex to match `p1` and `p2` and capture the values I want within them?

Comment: And the string always ends with `)`?

Comment: Tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kL0iW9/1), works fine.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the specifics of JS regexes, but I know your issue is the matching is non-greedy and needs to be greedy  I'd google for "greedy regex javascript" and see what can be seen. (note: in most languages that I know, regexes are greedy by default, so maybe there's something you've accidentally updated to make it work the other way)

Comment: @TarynEast But he is using a greedy operator `.*`.

Comment: @Xero Yes - which is why i'm saying it's odd that he's getting a non-greedy result.

Comment: BTW, `p1` and `p2` declared and initialized as shown yields a syntax error (*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL* in Chrome). These statements are supposed to **1)** initialize with quoted values and **2)** be semicolon-terminated, correct? For example, I take it that you meant `var p2='@VAL([Test1Q1].[Usages (KB)])';` or `var p2="@VAL([Test1Q1].[Usages (KB)])";` rather than `var p2=@VAL([Test1Q1].[Usages (KB)])`.  Single or double quotes did not make a difference when I checked, but you cannot match anything with `p1` and `p2` created as shown.

Answer (score 0):

As @Xero commented, the pattern matches both the input strings provided.

You can confirm this and see how to get the capture groups' values in the following snippet:

```js
var p1='@VAL([Test1Q1].[Bandwidth])';
var p2='@VAL([Test1Q1].[Usages (KB)])';
var fieldPattern = /@VAL\((.*)\)/;
var P1_Pattern = p1.match(fieldPattern)[1];
var P2_Pattern = p2.match(fieldPattern)[1];
// FORNOW: Use alerts and console logging to show the capture groups' values.
console.log("P1_Pattern === '" + P1_Pattern + "'");
alert("P1_Pattern === '" + P1_Pattern + "'");
console.log("P2_Pattern === '" + P2_Pattern + "'");
alert("P2_Pattern === '" + P2_Pattern + "'");
```

The snippet should output the following:

```
P1_Pattern === '[Test1Q1].[Bandwidth]'
P2_Pattern === '[Test1Q1].[Usages (KB)]'
```

Comment: @DavidKnipe: That is a very good question. I have seen OPs *think* that their code does not work...to then find that it does. Demonstrably answering that their code does, in fact, seem to work has led them to **a)** realize that their code really *does* work or **b)** reassert that it does not work *for them*...typically with some additional information that suggests why (e.g. an environmental difference like the browser in question). Hopefully the answer I have offered will trigger this "workflow" to get to the bottom-line.